# Invalid Parameters Execption using sequence

Tags: c#, winforms, using-statement

I have the following code (where `res.shuffle` is an image, `ein.Shuffle` is a bool and `kontrast` is the kontrast-color of BackColor):

```
using (Bitmap img = Code.EditImageColor(res.shuffle, (ein.Shuffle ? BackColor : kontrast)))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
    thumbnailToolbarButton1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(img.GetHicon());
}
```

Here is the method for the image processing (in `Code` class):

```
public static Bitmap EditImageColor(Image img, Color color)
{
    Bitmap scrBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
    Color oldcolor;
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(scrBitmap.Width, scrBitmap.Height);

    for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++)
        {
            oldcolor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
            newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(oldcolor.A, color));
        }
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

But every time I run it, it says

> System.ArgumentExeption (additional: `Invalid Parameters`)

pointing to the `Application.Run(new Form1());` code block in my `Program.cs` file.

> StackTrace: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll.`

I also tried it with `pictureBox1.Image` or `thumbnailToolbarButton1.Icon` standing alone in the statement.

Why is this caused? And how to prevent it to cause?

Thanks for any help! :D

**PS:**

Sorry for any typos and if I've written something "contently wrong", due to I'm new to `StackOverflow`.

Comment: @LarsTech: the `using` code block is the only code inside my `Form1_Load`-Event.

Comment: Why do you have your `imga` in a `using` when you are obviously setting it to `pictureBox1.Image`.  After the `using` the image will be disposed and the `pictureBox1.Image` will be invalid.  On the other hand you should be disposing of the intermediate `scrBitmap` image in the `EditImageColor` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, very simple answer:

when the bitmap was set as image of pictureBox1, it gets disposed. (Thanks to @juharr for commenting this)
Caused by disposing, the image gets invalid for the pictureBox & the exception will be thrown.

How to prevent this:

Don't use a using statement, just always use the same bitmap.

```
Bitmap imga = ...;
pictureBox0.Image = imga;
pictureBox1.Image = imga;
pictureBox2.Image = imga;
pictureBox3.Image = imga;
imga = ...;
pictureBox4.Image = imga;
pictureBox5.Image = imga;
pictureBox6.Image = imga;
pictureBox7.Image = imga;
...
```